# No Sound for separate audio file Blender Video Editor

Tags: audio

New installation of Blender 2.78a
Windows 10

I have added a video file to the Video Sequence Editor and the sound plays without issue.

I have added a wav file but no sound is produced.  Then I tried an mp3 file and again no sound is produced.

No the audio is not set to muted.

Any ideas?

Comment: This sounds weird (pun intended) :) the only reasons that come to mind could be (just considering all): strip muted (but you checked), bad wav/mp3 but I'm sure you checked, strip volume down to zero, blender master volume down to zero, some blender files corruption... and in the end, win10 or your pc doing something... also did you try that file on another pc?

Comment: Thanks for responding.  WOW something bazaar must have happened when I copied the audio file from my music directory to the Blender Asset directory. The file in the Blender directory had no sound even in WinAmp. Deleted the asset files and recopied the audio and now there is sound. Problem solved. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

m.ardito hinted that the audio files might be corrupted, and apparently they were. Don't know how on a simple copy paste but it happened. So deleting the audio files and replacing them solved the issue.